# Multiple Matrix blocks on one page

Tags: entries, matrix

I'm having a bit of difficulty having 2 different matrix blocks show on one page, and they both have Entries fields. As soon as I put `{% set entry` for my first Matrix, the second Matrix disappears.

```
{% for block in entry.sideMenu %}
 {% if block.type == "sideMenuItem" %}
    {% set entry = block.sideLink.first() %}
      {% if entry %}
         <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ block.sideTitle }}</a>
      {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how Craft handles [routing](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing) you will see this:

> If the URI matches an entry’s or category’s URI, the section’s/category group’s template will get loaded, and the matched element will be made available to the template via a pre-populated `entry` or `category` variable.

So Craft is assigning that `entry` variable that you are referencing on line 1 of your code. Then on line 3, you do `{% set entry = block.sideLink.first() %}` which overwrites that initial `entry` variable with this new value, which is why the second matrix disappears.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
{% for block in entry.sideMenu %}
  {% if block.type == "sideMenuItem" %}
    {% set sideLinkEntry = block.sideLink.first() %}
    {% if sideLinkEntry %}
       <a href="{{ sideLinkEntry.url }}">{{ block.sideTitle }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And your original `entry` will be unmodified.

Comment: Oh hells yeah that worked! Thanks so much, i can finally move on with my life!

Comment: Glad I could help! Hope I managed to make the whole thing a bit less mysterious